# SQL Server - Windows Active Directory users

Tags: sql-server

I am actually using SQL server for my application. If I work with one user (Install and Update app with WIX installer) everything works good, but if I try to change me windows user account to the other user, who can work with such database, but do not have Login of the user who was installing app with publishing DB, in Logins directory in SSMS. This user uses SQL Server Authentication. Is there a way to allow users who are in the Windows Active directory in domain admin group to add them all database previlages? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you may add your domain admin group by following steps:-

1. Right-click on the Logins under Security at your database server:
   [image: New Login]
2. Add new login under Windows authentication:
   [image: Windows authentication]
3. Tick sysadmin at Server Roles page:
   [image: sysadmin Server Roles]

Notes: Be careful to the server roles you are assigning to your domain admin group users, just assign the minimum privilege they need for their jobs.

Read more on Server-level roles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Another way to go would be to grant the group DBO to the needed (or all) databases. Don't hand out SA unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You're most welcome!